# How to change datetime field format on Sitecore backend

Tags: sitecore

Does anyone know the easiest way to change DateTime field format on Sitecore backend (Content Editor). My current Sitecore shows date in US format (which is MM/dd/yyyy); but I want to use the format dd/MM/yyyy.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Ben's suggestion, I've figured out what config I should change to achieve my goal: Since my region is using UK format, I need to change this for all users; and the config I need to change is DefaultRegionalIsoCode.

```
<setting name="DefaultRegionalIsoCode" value="en-GB" />
```

Jen's answer is also helpful, but it addresses another issue. From what I've researched, changing ClientLanguage needs to install additional package and may translate all texts/messages of the whole CMS.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Client_Translations/CMS%20Client%20Translations/7,-d-,0,-d-,x.aspx

Answer (score 5):

This is controlled by the language the shell/Sitecore backend is running in (not the content language). By default Sitecore uses english (US). If you run with this language it will show the format in MM/dd/yyyy.

If you have a danish language it will show dd-MM-yyyy. If you need an english language with another date format, you should probably create a en-UK language in the core database, and have your users log in to that format.

You can also set the default language for the content editor by setting the following configuration in the web.config

```
<setting name="ClientLanguage" value="da" />
```

Comment: Hi, could you show me where to change the default language? I know it's on core database but not sure where. By the way, there are plenty of items have been created under en-US language, is there a way to convert them to en-GB without losing data? Thank you.

Comment: Note that it is not content language, so it doesn't matter which language the items are in. We are talking client/shell/Sitecore backend language which is controlled under the core database under /sitecore/system/languages. I have added a default setting to the answer

Comment: Hi, I've changed this setting but it didn't work. I later figured out that I need to import some packages (http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Client_Translations/CMS%20Client%20Translations/7,-d-,0,-d-,x.aspx) to complete this. However, I've found my answer from Ben's suggestion. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the system-wide default mentioned by Jens, this can be controlled on a per-user basis by changing the Regional ISO Code on the Language Settings tab of the Edit User dialog.  A user can also change it by going to Control Panel > Preferences > Set Your Regional and Language Options.

Comment: Hi, it works. And I found out the system-wide solution as well. Thank you very much.